# Conky cpubar filling in wrong way

Tags: lua, kde-plasma, conky

I have a simple conky cpubar for monitoring CPU load working on Debian KDE 9, here is the relevant part:

```
${image ~/script/conky/static/img/cpu.png -p 0,280 -s 26x26}\
${goto 40}${font monospace:bold:size=15}${color1}CPU ${font   monospace:bold:size=10}(TOT: ${cpu cpu0}%) ${color0}${hr 5}${color white}

${font monospace:bold:size=11}\
${execi 99999 neofetch | grep 'CPU' | cut -f 2 -d ":" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | sed 's/[\x01-\x1F\x7F]//g' | sed 's/\[0m//g' | sed 's/\[.*\]//'}\
[${execi 5 sensors | grep 'temp1' | cut -c16-22}]
${cpugraph cpu0 40,340 52ff00 6edd21}
CPU 1${goto 70}${cpu cpu1}%${goto 100}${cpubar 8,width_cpu_bar cpu1}
CPU 2${goto 70}${cpu cpu2}%${goto 100}${cpubar 8,width_cpu_bar cpu2}
CPU 3${goto 70}${cpu cpu3}%${goto 100}${cpubar 8,width_cpu_bar cpu3}
CPU 4${goto 70}${cpu cpu4}%${goto 100}${cpubar 8,width_cpu_bar cpu4}
```

Ad this is the result:

[image]

Another example:

[image]

As you can see the result looks good but the filling cpubars dont work properly and all 4 bars have the same filling, clearly seen in the last one where I have a 100% core load (CPU3) and his bar is not completely full.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cpu number comes before the *height,width* part, i.e. use

```
${cpubar cpu1 8,width_cpu_bar}
```